# searchbox.send_keys() is unable to write any text on the bar by itself

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
[from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://youtube.com')
searchbox = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="search"]')
searchbox.send_keys("Akram Khan")
searchButton = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]')
searchButton.click()]
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/egHm1.png)

**The function [searchbox.send_keys("Akram Khan")] have to be write the mentioned text("Akram Khan") inside the search box of YouTUbe.**

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that when you first try to get the searchbox element with the current version that you had it was searching for the first occurrence of an element with id='search' which there is an element that is before not connected to the search box (therefore send_keys() to that element doesn't work). You can get the specific element that you want by specifying the tag that it is with your current code by doing (because the input element is what you want to be sending your response to):

```
searchbox = driver.find_element("xpath",'//input[@id="search"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

@id='search' is reflecting to list of elements so use unique element like @name='search-query'